# Submit button styles change when validation errors occur

Tags: html, css, button

I have a form for collecting some personal data and build the whole web site using the Foundation Framework. Yesterday I realized that my form field validation was not good enough and so I've decided to use the jQuery Validator plug-in. It validates OK, but now I have a styling problem with my submit button, which disappears to the right. This is probably because my div for the form does not have a flexible height. Take a look:

[image]

The form is fairly long, so I created a JSFiddle with the relevant coding (see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/w7vsxdqs/2/).

HTML:

```
<p>
    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</p>
```

CSS:

```
#submit-button {
  text-indent:-9999px;
  display:block;
  background:url('../img/get-free-quote.png') no-repeat; 
  border: medium none;
  height: 56px;
  width: 222px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 300px; }
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $("#form").validate(
              {
                rules:
                {
                  x_C1Forename:
                  {
                    required: true
                  },
                    x_C1Surname:
                  {
                    required: true
                  },
                  x_C1Email:
                  {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                  },
                  x_C1HomeTel:
                  {
                     required: true,
                     number: true  
                  },
                  x_C1Street:
                  {
                     required: true
                  },
                  x_C1Postcode:
                  {
                     required: true
                  }
                },
                messages:
                {
                  x_C1Forename:
                  {
                    required: "Please enter your first name"
                  },
                  x_C1Surname:
                  {
                    required: "Please enter your surname"
                  },    
                  x_C1Email:
                  {
                    required: "Please enter your email address.",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address."   
                  },
                  x_C1HomeTel:
                  {
                     required: "Please enter your phone number.",
                     number: "Please enter a valid phone number."
                  },
                  x_C1Street:
                  {
                     required: "Please enter your street's name."
                  },
                  x_C1Postcode:
                  {
                     required: "Please enter your postcode"
                  }    
                }
              });   
            </script>
```

The result in the fiddle will not help you much, but one can get the basic idea.
I would really appreciate an advise as to what method should make this work properly,so that the validation does its part and the button stays on its place too.
Thanks in advance!
Daniel

Comment: Your fiddle loads neither jQuery nor validate.js

Comment: The fiddle doesn't display quite right, but you are setting a fixed height on the `form` and on `#form-box` on small screens, so the error messages seem to push the button outside the boundaries. Do you need to set a fixed height - maybe `min-height` will work better?

Comment: The JavaScript and validation plugin have nothing to do with how the button is displayed.  When the messages are inserted, your content (the button) no longer fits into the box.  This is entirely an issue of HTML and CSS that needs to better accommodate dynamically inserted content.

Comment: *"This is probably because my div for the form does not have a flexible height."* - So, have you tried giving it a flexible height? If you don't want that, where do you want the button to go?